# zend custom validator not working

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2

I have created a custom validator in Zend 2.2. But the behavior is strange.
This is my form

```
namespace module\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class HistoryForm extends Form {

    public function __construct($name = null){
    parent::__construct('History'); 
    $filter = new InputFilter('ReportingCurrencyHistoryFilter');

    //  creating a form element.
        $efrm = new Element\Text('effective_from');
        $efrm->setLabel("Effective From");
        $efrm->setAttributes(array(
                'id'  => 'effective_from', 'required'=>'required', 'maxlength'=>10, 'size'=>10
        ));

        //  adding the form element to the form
        $this->add($efrm);

    //  Effective Till

        //  creating a form field 
        $etill = new Element\Text('effective_till');
        $etill->setLabel("Reporting Currency 'Effective Till'");
        $etill->setAttributes(array(
                'id'  => 'effective_till', 'maxlength'=>10, 'size'=>10
        ));

        //adding an element to the form
        $this->add($etill); 

        // creating new filter for the field
        $flt_eftill = new Input('effective_till');  

        //  assigning the custom validator and attaching to the filter
        $etill_history_conflict = new \APP\CustomValidators\HistoryConflict();
        $flt_eftill->getFilterChain()->attach($etill_history_conflict);

        //  add the filter chain to filter object
        $filter->add($flt_eftill);

        //  setting the filter as input filter for the form
        $this->setInputFilter($filter);

    //  Submit button

        $submit = new Element\Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttribute('value', 'Submit');
        $this->add($submit);
    }
}
```

Here is my custom validator class

```
namespace APP\CustomValidators;

use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class HistoryConflict extends AbstractValidator{

    const ERROR_NO_DATA    = 'nodata';
    const ERROR_CONFLICT    = 'conflict';

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
            self::ERROR_NO_DATA  => "No data entered. this is a mandatory field",
            self::ERROR_CONFLICT => "This data has conflict with previous history",
    );
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);
        $valid = true;
        if(!trim($value))
        {
            $this->error(self::ERROR_NO_DATA);
            $valid = false;
        }
        if(!is_array($value))   //
        {
            $this->error(self::ERROR_CONFLICT);
            //echo $value . '<br />';
            $valid = false;
        }
        return $valid;
    }
}
```

I purposely did is_array check in my validator to fail the validation to see the error message specified in the custom validator. But when i fill in something and submit the form, i get

> Value is required and can't be empty

instead of

> This data has conflict with previous history (specified in custom validator)

This is my controller part

```
public function insertAction(){
    if($this->request->isPost())
    {
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('HistoryForm');
        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $model = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Historymodel');
            $arr_sess = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ImsAcs\Model\AuthStorage')->read();
            if($model->insert($form->getData(),$post['hdOfficeId'], $arr_sess['userName']))
            {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Data has been updated Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Data was not added");
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('module/default' , array(
                        'controller'=>'History',
                        'action' =>  'insert',
                        'id'=>$post['parId']
                ));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($form->errorMessage());

            $this->layout()->setVariables(array(
                    'messages' => array("There were one or more issues with your submission. Please correct them as inticated below."),
            )
            );

            $view = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'action' => $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index')));
            $view->setTemplate('model/history/historyForm');
            return $view;
        }
    }
}
```

In controller if i print the error message after $form->isValid(), i get

> Array ( [effective_till] => Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and
>   can't be empty ) )

Someone please help why the custom validator message was not displayed?

Comment: Can you provide your controller code?

Comment: @OlegKrivtsov i have updated the controller code